# Windows 10 - keeps braking network connection

Tags: windows-10, networking

After recent Windows Insiders update I have started getting crazy annoying issue - using any other network port than web is braking the connection almost immediately.

E.g. when I try to watch a move on TV served by Plex server - connection gets broken after less than a minute,
When I try to download IDE update through Jetbrains Toolbox - connection gets broken in seconds,
When I try to start torrents - it brakes in seconds too.

Then I have to turn card off and on and it works again immediately, but this is crazy annoying.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: so this is wifi or wired? are other devices on the network affected? how are you connected to the internet, and what precisely do you mean by turning the card off and back on? are you disabling the nic in the windows control panel, and then reenabling it?

Comment: 1. Wired
2. No, I can freely use wifi on the phone without any issues
3. Through the router from my ISP
4. Exactly - control panel off/on

Comment: I would suggest you could collect network traffic via Wireshark or Network Monitor to see if the network traffic can be sent out when connect wired network.

Comment: so when its in a broken state, can you ping your router by IP address, or resolve a dns name with a command like `nslookup www.google.com`?